# returning array from Model to Controller codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, return

I'm trying to query two values from database, with 2 different IDs and I need to get all the results on one array. This is part of my controller.

```
function account()
{
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $this->load->model("Site_model");
    $q = $this->Site_model->get_all_notify($user_id);
}
```

and here is the Model:

```
function get_user_data_by_id($id) {
    $this->db->where("id",$id);
    $q=$this->db->get("users");
    return  $q->result();
}

function get_all_notify($user_id) {
    $this->db->where("wanted_id",$user_id);
    $this->db->where("requests_id",1);
    $q=$this->db->get("intrested");
    foreach($q->result() as $row) {
        $user=$this->get_user_data_by_id($row->users_id);
    }
    return $user;
}
```

But when I print_r $q from controller I only get 1 row... but when I print_r $user I get all the results! Even with foreach nothing seems to work!

Comment: You are *overwriting* `$user` on each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make array and store the users data in that,in current code the last iteration data from foreach will be return

```
$user=array();
foreach($q->result() as $row)
{
        $user[]=$this->get_user_data_by_id($row->users_id);
}
return $user;
```

Comment: that worked for controller, but when I passed that variable who returned from Model to view like($this->load->view("include/template",$data); when I try to foreach it on view I can't access to any indexes, when I print_r $data it gives me the correct record as an array, but I need username index, I can't use $data['username'] or $data->username or $data[3]. How can I get any values from that array!!

Comment: In `get_user_data_by_id($id)` change `$q->result();` to `$q->row();` if there is only one user per passed id

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck for 5 hours you saved my days. I don't understand what was wrong though! what is wrong of sending ->row() or ->result()?

Comment: @yasser `result()` will returns the multiple records each record n array format and `row()` will give only one record